# What is this jazz song in the first episode of Gundam Thunderbolt?

Tags: music, gundam

I've been looking for the name of this jazz piece in the first episode of *Gundam Thunderbolt*. I'm more curious to know whether it's an original song for the OST or not. It can be found at the following times:

- 1:57 - 2:27
- 3:27 - 4:16

Comment: It's this song, right? Can't seem to find the released track so it may not have dropped yet but it is a song of the show. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6jTb2FQ_ow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one that maybe your looking for :3

[Gundam Thunderbolt OST 01 - Thunderbolt For Main Theme (Io Fleming Song)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrLvoyFpLGc)